# Authorization: Any Benefit of OAuth2 for First-Party Web and Mobile Clients

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, authorization, bearer-token

I would like to know whether there is any security benefit to using OAuth2 for authorization where all clients are developed, owned and controlled by the API developer/owner/controller; as opposed to using token authentication per [Django Rest Framework's Token Authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

My understanding OAuth is that it was created for the purpose of delegated authorization - allowing third party applications access to your user's data without knowing the user's credentials. It seems to now have become a standard, even where delegation is not required. I do not understand why. Is there any benefit at all where delegation is not required?

My setup will be a Django Rest Framework API with a web SPA client and mobile clients. Permissions are associated with user accounts. Users login with email and password.

I do not think that this is an opinion question, because I'm not asking which is better, I will make that decision myself, I'm just trying to understand whether there is actually any security benefit at all to the OAuth option. This question might be somewhat open-ended but hopefully is within an acceptable margin since I'm restricting the considerations to security considerations. Developer effort etc are not necessary to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is primarily a set of best practice security design patterns, represented by [standards specifications](https://curity.io/product/conformance/#supported-standards) that map to use cases for software companies. It is not just about delegation.

I wouldn't say solutions are `more secure` just because OAuth is used. It is more a case of the threats being better thought through, as well as the general architecture.

**PROTECTING DATA IN APIs**

The OAuth solution involves validating a JWT access token on every request, then using `claims` to implement the real authorization work.

This scales well to zero trust architectures, where JWTs can be forwarded between APIs, and the `scope` and `audience` claims can be used for boundary checks. The [IAM Primer](https://curity.io/resources/learn/iam-primer/) provides a good overview.

**UI FLOWS**

Web and mobile are tricky, and it is worth being aware of [SPA Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spa-best-practices/), whether you use OAuth or any other solution, such as a site that manages its own passwords.

**FULL OAUTH SOLUTIONS**

A full OAuth solution involves use of a third party Authorization Server (AS), which manages the difficult security work, but there is a learning curve in integrating one. It also enables you to use the [code flow](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-code-flow/), which is worth reading about.

Sometimes companies adopt an AS when they want multiple sign in methods, custom authentication, business partner integration, or to use advanced flows or [financial grade security](https://curity.io/resources/learn/what-is-financial-grade/), which is required in some industry sectors.

**YOUR SOLUTION**

Securíty for web, mobile and APIs is difficult however you do it. Usually companies identify requirements and design how they want end-to-end flows to work, rather than it just being a developer task. My [blog post](https://thenewstack.io/essentials-for-integrating-identity/) suggests a people process.

My general recommendation would be to follow OAuth patterns to protect data, even if you implement UI flows in a simpler way initially. Your code will then be migratable to a full OAuth architecture in future, if your security requirements evolve.